# How can I deploy multiple apigateway via one serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using serverless to deploy apigateway and it seems one serverless yml file can only deploy one type of API gateway?

My use case is to deploy 2 apigateway both are rest. One is public, the other is private. Is it possible to use one serverless yml file to configure both?

Comment: 2 API Gateway APIs integrated with single lambda or any other service?

Comment: 2 apigateway integrate with different lambdas. All lambdas are in the same severless.yml stack.